# WPF MVVM Where do you put UI Functions that wouldn't appear on your ViewModel

Tags: wpf

My understanding is that when you take your View and say:
    myView.DataContext = myViewModel;

You are kind of assigning the class that it should refer to, almost like the code-behind in a most apps.  I've always loved the design but where is the best place to put display type logic that really doesn't belong in your view model?  For example say you're modifying a context menu for an item depending on the item's status.  In the past I've handled different bits of display functionality with converters.  I was going to use the Views native code behind but then I realized I don't think I have access to that do I?

Comment: Specific questions get specific answers. So to answer your question as you asked it, hmmmm... put it somewhere.

Comment: a `ContextMenu` is just a bunch of `ICommand`s. I don't see why these wouldn't belong into the ViewModel...

Comment: There is nothing wrong with putting View-Specific code in the code-behind the View when using MVVM, however in your case of modifying `ContextMenu` commands based on a selected item, that sounds like it should belong in the `ViewModel` :)

Comment: Context menu is probably a bad example.  Say for instance I have a list of items.  My viewmodel exposes with those items a status.  I want the view to render certain things depending on that status ( Like draw this shape and change these colors etc)  It doesn't feel like that should be in the ViewModel, but I don't know how to reference functions in the actual codebehind of the view since I changed the datacontext.

Comment: I like to use MVPVM - Model View Presenter View Model.  By this I mean having certain presenter classes that interact with the view to do this kind of thing.  Usually as attached behaviors.  Keeps the view clean with minimal code behind and encapsulates control logic in a behavior class that can be re-used

Comment: I've updated the code to a more specific example based on feedback.  Any input would be welcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My assumption that setting the DataContext for a View was the same as pointing it to a different code behind file was incorrect.  The DataContext is used for binding purposes.  You can still reference methods in the normal code behind like so:

```
<CheckBox Margin="5,0,30,0" 
                         x:Name="OSHPD" IsChecked="{Binding OSHPD}" 
                         Validation.ErrorTemplate="{x:Null}" Checked="OSHPD_Checked" Unchecked="OSHPD_Unchecked">OSHPD Approval</CheckBox>

private void OSHPD_Checked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        FM.IsEnabled = false;

    }
    private void OSHPD_Unchecked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        FM.IsEnabled = true;
    }
```

Databinding IsChecked="{Binding OSHPD}" is hitting the ViewModel while the events Checked="OSHPD_Checked" Unchecked="OSHPD_Unchecked" reference the Views code behind.

Answer (score 0):

Typically you would have a model object for each item in your list.  Then wrap each model in a view model.  The view model would then expose properties for the attributes you described (colors, fonts, etc.) and fire property change notifications.  Hope that helps.

Comment: I can kind of see this, but then its basically a UI ViewModel only.  Is this okay?

Comment: The viewmodel would also have properties to expose the model's properties that you want to bind to in your data template, for example.

Answer (score 0):

Most things that go in a View's code behind could also go in a ValueConverter, Behavior or AttachedProperty. Each of these will be able to access Control level properties. Generally you are able to supply these with values like the colours/brushes/shapes and other view specific data, to keep the valueConverter/behaviour/AttachedProperty generic if you did find you needed to reuse it.